# Getting error with ansible_date_time.epoch when subtracting dates

Tags: ansible, epoch

I am using `ansible_date_time.epoch` to calculate days since a server was built. I get the build date information from a csv file and trying to do a calculation, but I am getting an error.

*serverInventory.csv*:

```
serverA,,,,,2019-04-24 19:57:34
serverB,,,,,2019-04-26 19:47:01
serverC,,,,,2020-08-20 23:30:25
```

Hosts:

```ini
serverA
serverB
serverC
```

Tasks:

```yaml
- name: List Server in current play
  debug:
    msg: "Item is {{ item }} Build date {{ lookup('csvfile', item + ' file=serverInventory.csv delimiter=, col=5') }}"
  loop: "{{ ansible_play_batch }}"

- name: Calculate  days since server build
  debug:
    msg:"{{ ((ansible_date_time.epoch | to_datetime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')) - svrBuildDate).days }}"
  vars:
    svrBuildDate: "{{ lookup('csvfile', inventory_hostname + ' file=serverInventory.csv delimiter=, col=5')  }}"
```

Output:

```
TASK [common : List Server in current play] *********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [serverA] => {
    "msg": "Item is serverA Build date 2019-04-24 19:57:34"
}
ok: [serverB] => {
    "msg": "Item is serverB Build date 2019-04-26 19:47:01"
}
ok: [serverC] => {
    "msg": "Item is serverC Build date 2020-08-20 23:30:25"
}

TASK [common : Calculate  days since server build] **************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [serverA]: FAILED! => {"msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value ({'_variable_params': u'msg:\"{{ ((ansible_date_time.epoch | to_datetime(\\'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\\')) - svrBuildDate).days }}\"'}), and could not be converted to an dict.The error was: time data '1655353270' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/ansible/server_build/roles/common/tasks/main.yml': line 25, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Calculate  days since server build\n  ^ here\n"}
fatal: [serverB]: FAILED! => {"msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value ({'_variable_params': u'msg:\"{{ ((ansible_date_time.epoch | to_datetime(\\'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\\')) - svrBuildDate).days }}\"'}), and could not be converted to an dict.The error was: time data '1655353271' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/ansible/server_build/roles/common/tasks/main.yml': line 25, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Calculate  days since server build\n  ^ here\n"}
fatal: [serverC]: FAILED! => {"msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value ({'_variable_params': u'msg:\"{{ ((ansible_date_time.epoch | to_datetime(\\'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\\')) - svrBuildDate).days }}\"'}), and could not be converted to an dict.The error was: time data '1655353273' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/ansible/server_build/roles/common/tasks/main.yml': line 25, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Calculate  days since server build\n  ^ here\n"}
        to retry, use: --limit @/ansible/server_build/site.retry

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
serverA             : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
serverB             : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
serverC             : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do computation on date, you need both elements to be `datetime`.
In your task, you are trying to subtract a `string`, from your CSV, to an epoch, which is of type `AnsibleUnsafeText`.

So you need:

1. The current date, in a `datetime` format, which can be achieved with

   ```
   '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' | strftime | to_datetime
   ```
2. The date from your CSV converted in a `datetime`, which can be achieved with

   ```
   lookup(
     'csvfile', inventory_hostname,
     file='serverInventory.csv', delimiter=',', col=5
   ) | to_datetime
   ```
3. Then only you can subtract the two of them

So, we end up with a task like:

```yaml
- name: Calculate  days since server build
  debug:
    msg: >-
      {{ 
         (
           currentDate | to_datetime 
           - dateFromInventory  | to_datetime
         ).days 
      }}
  vars:
    currentDate: "{{ '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' | strftime }}"
    dateFromInventory: >-
      {{
        lookup(
          'csvfile', inventory_hostname,
          file='serverInventory.csv', delimiter=',', col=5
        )
      }}
```

Which would, on your example CSV, yield:

```yaml
ok: [serverA] => 
  msg: '1148'
ok: [serverB] => 
  msg: '1146'
ok: [serverC] => 
  msg: '664'
```

Comment: β.εηοιτ.βε, thank you for pointing out the problem and provide the solution. I have one more question there is additional process I need to do within the 'Calculate days since server build' task.  I need to use the result to ssh to each box and update a file on each server if the result is greater than 30 days.  Can you suggest on how to implement this additional step.  Thanks

Comment: Well, then instead of debugging something write the file based on a condition from the same data, something like: `when: (currentDate | to_datetime  - dateFromInventory  | to_datetime).days | int > 30`